# Create database diagram with tables relationships

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key, relationship

I have a task:
There are meals and there are products that are used to cook meals. There are calculation of meals - a description of how much and what kind of products used for the preparation of a certain number of meals. The calculation may change over time.
You must create a database that would store a list of products, meals and calculations of meals. The database should provide answers to the following questions:

- How much and what kind of products you need to prepare a certain number of specified meals at the specified point in time?
- What meals can be cooked with a specified prduct for a specified point in time?

The problem I'm facing is with the change of calculations over time. How do I do something with the change over time? Do I create another table for that? I will need a databse diagram with PK and FK relationships.
Right now I have this diagram:
[image: Diagram]

Comment: Well @Dan did you tried anything?

Comment: @ShreyasTg I edited the question  - added my diagram.